# How to sort a Laravel query builder result by multiple columns?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I want to sort multiple columns in Laravel 4 by using the method `orderBy()` in Laravel Eloquent. The query will be generated using Eloquent like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
ORDER BY
  coloumn1 DESC, coloumn2 ASC
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Very simple. `User::orderBy('name', 'DESC')
    ->orderBy('email', 'ASC')
    ->get();`

Answer (score 554, accepted):

Simply invoke `orderBy()` as many times as you need it. For instance:

```
User::orderBy('name', 'DESC')
    ->orderBy('email', 'ASC')
    ->get();
```

Produces the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` ORDER BY `name` DESC, `email` ASC
```

Comment: It would be nice if we could pass an array like:                  `User::orderBy(array('name'=>'desc', 'email'=>'asc'))`

Comment: @FireCoding, you can do `$user->orders = array(array('column' => 'name', 'direction' => 'desc'), array('column' => 'email', 'direction' => 'asc'));`

Comment: Is there a way to add an orderBy on an established query?

Comment: @Rafael, if you haven't already ran it (called `get` or `first`), just call `orderBy` on it. Else, nope.

Comment: Otherwise, if you always need to order by desc, then you can use latest() too.

Comment: In this article https://lavalite.org/blog/using-orderby-for-multiple-columns-laravel said we can use `User::orderBy(array('name'=>'desc', 'email'=>'asc'))`. But i got error `stripos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`. Why? @rmobis

Comment: @RayCoder I wouldn't know. Neither the method I posted here nor the one on the article seem to be present on the official documentation and the API page for Laravel 4 (which is where I found it at first) is no longer up. However, my guess would be that the article's method doesn't work, and it couldn't. Because `orderBy` needs to know the order of the columns it was given, and it can't do that when you use string keys, as `['a' => 1, 'b' => 1]`  is the same as `['b' => 1, 'a' => 1]`.

Answer (score 73):

You can do as @rmobis has specified in his answer, [Adding something more into it]

**Using `order by` twice:**

```
MyTable::orderBy('coloumn1', 'DESC')
    ->orderBy('coloumn2', 'ASC')
    ->get();
```

and the second way to do it is,

**Using `raw order by`:**

```
MyTable::orderByRaw("coloumn1 DESC, coloumn2 ASC");
    ->get();
```

Both will produce same query as follow,

```
SELECT * FROM `my_tables` ORDER BY `coloumn1` DESC, `coloumn2` ASC
```

As @rmobis specified in comment of first answer you can **pass like an array to order by column** like this,

```
$myTable->orders = array(
    array('column' => 'coloumn1', 'direction' => 'desc'), 
    array('column' => 'coloumn2', 'direction' => 'asc')
);
```

one more way to do it is `iterate` in loop,

```
$query = DB::table('my_tables');

foreach ($request->get('order_by_columns') as $column => $direction) {
    $query->orderBy($column, $direction);
}

$results = $query->get();
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: can i used orderByRaw AND orderBy together? doesnt seem to work for me, the resulting query only seems to respect orderByRaw

Comment: try to put orderBy first and then orderByRaw and see the result @GeorgeAvgoustis

Comment: unfortunately this cannot be done as it first needs to be randomized and then order by the final qualifier.

Comment: It does work together might be because applying on first column sorting you can not see second column sorting

Answer (score 13):

Use order by like this:

```
return User::orderBy('name', 'DESC')
    ->orderBy('surname', 'DESC')
    ->orderBy('email', 'DESC')
    ...
    ->get();
```

Comment: That is what I do , but in my case I would like that if two users have the same surname, the corresponding entries respect the  naming order .  Any Ideas?

Comment: @Berni, the order you add your `orderBy` it should get executed. So, `order by surname asc, name desc` or something like that should be in your query. so your eloquent should be written in that order as well!

Answer (score 6):

Here's another dodge that I came up with for my base repository class where I needed to order by an arbitrary number of columns:

```
public function findAll(array $where = [], array $with = [], array $orderBy = [], int $limit = 10)
{
    $result = $this->model->with($with);
    $dataSet = $result->where($where)
        // Conditionally use $orderBy if not empty
        ->when(!empty($orderBy), function ($query) use ($orderBy) {
            // Break $orderBy into pairs
            $pairs = array_chunk($orderBy, 2);
            // Iterate over the pairs
            foreach ($pairs as $pair) {
                // Use the 'splat' to turn the pair into two arguments
                $query->orderBy(...$pair);
            }
        })
        ->paginate($limit)
        ->appends(Input::except('page'));

    return $dataSet;
}
```

Now, you can make your call like this:

```
$allUsers = $userRepository->findAll([], [], ['name', 'DESC', 'email', 'ASC'], 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->data['user_posts'] = User_posts::with(['likes', 'comments' => function($query) { $query->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC'); }])->where('status', 1)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();
```

Comment: Code only answers are discourage on SO, please add some explanation.

Comment: the method you posted is not working. will you be able to explain a bit