# How to count distinct values from a collection in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have been struggling on how to get the quantity of distinct values from a collection in Eloquent.

I have been trying several methods, such as unique(), values(), etc., found on the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections). Even though there is indeed a count() method, there is no method to get the count of distinct values.

For example, by applying the following query

```
$technicalshighestdegrees = Capsule::table('academicinfo AS fa')
        ->selectRaw('DISTINCT fa.academic_id AS Id,c.name AS Degree')
        ->leftJoin('academics AS a','fa.academic_id','=','a.id')
        ->leftJoin('cat_degree AS c','fa.level','=','c.id')
        ->whereIn('a.type',['Technical'])
        ->where('a.status','!=','Retired')
        ->where('c.degree',true)
        ->orderBy('a.id')
        ->orderBy('c.hierarchy','desc')/*http://stackoverflow.com/a/17006377/1883256*/
        ->get();
```

I get this collection:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 3
                    [Grado] => Master
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 3
                    [Grado] => Bachelor
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 4
                    [Grado] => Master
                )

            [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 4
                    [Grado] => Bachelor
                )

            [4] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 6
                    [Grado] => Master
                )

            [5] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 6
                    [Grado] => Bachelor
                )

            [6] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 18
                    [Grado] => Bachelor
                )

            [7] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 27
                    [Grado] => Bachelor
                )

            [8] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 34
                    [Grado] => Master
                )

            [9] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 34
                    [Grado] => Bachelor
                )

            [10] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 36
                    [Grado] => PhD
                )

            [11] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 36
                    [Grado] => Master
                )

            [12] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 36
                    [Grado] => Bachelor
                )

            [13] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 37
                    [Grado] => Bachelor
                )

            [14] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 42
                    [Grado] => PhD
                )

            [15] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 42
                    [Grado] => Master
                )

            [16] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 42
                    [Grado] => Bachelor
                )

            [17] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 50
                    [Grado] => Bachelor
                )

            [18] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 52
                    [Grado] => Bachelor
                )

            [19] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 53
                    [Grado] => Master
                )

            [20] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 53
                    [Grado] => Bachelor
                )

            [21] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 54
                    [Grado] => Master
                )

            [22] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 54
                    [Grado] => Bachelor
                )

            [23] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 55
                    [Grado] => Master
                )

            [24] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 55
                    [Grado] => Bachelor
                )

            [25] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 57
                    [Grado] => Bachelor
                )

            [26] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 68
                    [Grado] => Master
                )

            [27] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 68
                    [Grado] => Bachelor
                )

            [28] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 72
                    [Grado] => Master
                )

            [29] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 72
                    [Grado] => Bachelor
                )

            [30] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 77
                    [Grado] => Bachelor
                )

            [31] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 82
                    [Grado] => Bachelor
                )

            [32] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 85
                    [Grado] => PhD
                )

            [33] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 85
                    [Grado] => Master
                )

            [34] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 85
                    [Grado] => Bachelor
                )

            [35] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 92
                    [Grado] => Master
                )

            [36] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 92
                    [Grado] => Bachelor
                )

            [37] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 100
                    [Grado] => Master
                )

            [38] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 100
                    [Grado] => Bachelor
                )

            [39] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 111
                    [Grado] => Bachelor
                )

            [40] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 117
                    [Grado] => Master
                )

            [41] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 117
                    [Grado] => Bachelor
                )

            [42] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 123
                    [Grado] => Master
                )

            [43] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 123
                    [Grado] => Bachelor
                )

        )

)
```

Since, I just want to get the highest degrees (a user Id may have several historical degrees), I apply the unique() method, that according to the docs, it leaves only the first original value, in my case, I have already ordered them by hierarchy desc:

```
$technicalshighestdegrees = $technicalshighestdegrees->unique('Id');
```

And now I get the following collection (reduced to 25 items, which is exactly the total number):

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 3
                    [Degree] => Master
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 4
                    [Degree] => Master
                )

            [4] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 6
                    [Degree] => Master
                )

            [6] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 18
                    [Degree] => Bachelor
                )

            [7] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 27
                    [Degree] => Bachelor
                )

            [8] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 34
                    [Degree] => Master
                )

            [10] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 36
                    [Degree] => PhD
                )

            [13] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 37
                    [Degree] => Bachelor
                )

            [14] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 42
                    [Degree] => PhD
                )

            [17] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 50
                    [Degree] => Bachelor
                )

            [18] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 52
                    [Degree] => Bachelor
                )

            [19] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 53
                    [Degree] => Master
                )

            [21] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 54
                    [Degree] => Master
                )

            [23] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 55
                    [Degree] => Master
                )

            [25] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 57
                    [Degree] => Bachelor
                )

            [26] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 68
                    [Degree] => Master
                )

            [28] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 72
                    [Degree] => Master
                )

            [30] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 77
                    [Degree] => Bachelor
                )

            [31] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 82
                    [Degree] => Bachelor
                )

            [32] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 85
                    [Degree] => PhD
                )

            [35] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 92
                    [Degree] => Master
                )

            [37] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 100
                    [Degree] => Master
                )

            [39] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 111
                    [Degree] => Bachelor
                )

            [40] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 117
                    [Degree] => Master
                )

            [42] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 123
                    [Degree] => Master
                )

        )

)
```

What I want is to get the quantities for each distinct degree value as follows:

```
Array
(
    [Master] => 13
    [Bachelor] => 9
    [PhD] => 3
)
```

But in an Eloquent collection...

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Update for 2021/L6+

*thanks @JeremyWadhams*

```php
$degrees->groupBy('Degree')->map(fn ($people) => $people->count());
// or using HigherOrder proxy on the collection
$degrees->groupBy('Degree')->map->count();
```

---

Using collection methods this would be it:

```php
$degrees->groupBy('Degree')->map(function ($people) {
    return $people->count();
});

// Collection {
//   'Master' => 13,
//   'Bachelor' => 9,
//   'PhD' => 3
// }
```

Comment: I love this trick, thank you!  You could simplify it one step more using the higher order map, like $degrees->groupBy('Degree')->map->count()

Comment: Hello sir, Is there any way to count number of these unique groups ? in your example count should be 3

Comment: @SagarGautam `$degrees->groupBy(..)->count()` will do the trick

Comment: @JeremyWadhams a bit late on my part, but thanks for your comment! Feel free to EDIT existing answers with such improvements - I'm sure everyone will appreciate your effort!

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk count doesn;t work with group by !

Answer (score 10):

There is a Collection Helper called CountBy, does exactly what you need.

[Collections CountBy](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-countBy)

```
$degrees->countBy('Degree');
```

It will retourn as expected

```
 Array
(
    [Master] => 13
    [Bachelor] => 9
    [PhD] => 3
)
```

Simple :D

Comment: Too bad this was posted after the original accepted answer, this would be the best way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

Could also do the following:

```
$master = $degrees->sum('Master');
return $master;

$bachelor = $degrees->sum('Bachelor');
return $bachelor;

$phD = $degrees->sum('PhD');
return $phD;
```

Comment: You are falling to de DRY principle