# how to sort rows as groups in sql

Tags: mysql, laravel, sql-order-by

I am using mysql and my rows are as follows

```
name   type
Alex   Bank Tranfer     
Alex   Easy 
Alex   Sec  
Alex   Easy 
Alex   Bank Tranfer     
Alex   Sec
```

I want the results to be like

```
Alex   Bank Tranfer     
Alex   Bank Tranfer 
Alex   Easy
Alex   Easy 
Alex   Sec  
Alex   Sec
```

`GROUP BY` clause get the single distinct rows.

What could be the sql for it?

I am using laravel framework if anyone knows how to do it in laravel will be appreciated.

Comment: In sort use same columns as in group. group by firstName, lastName order by firstName, lastName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [docs for Laravel query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset) show only ordering by a single column:

```
$users = DB::table('NoOneNamesTheirTableInSQLQuestions')
                ->orderBy('name', 'asc')
                ->get();
```

But a quick search [finds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17006309/how-to-use-order-by-for-multiple-columns-in-laravel-4) that you can repeat the `orderBy()` function to add more columns:

```
$users = DB::table('NoOneNamesTheirTableInSQLQuestions')
                ->orderBy('name', 'asc')
                ->orderBy('type', 'asc')
                ->get();
```