# Orderby multiple columns

Tags: php, laravel, sql-order-by, laravel-backpack

I'm using Backpack for Laravel, Crud module.

How to use orderby() for multiple columns?

example:

```
$this->crud->orderBy('name','desc')->orderBy('year,'asc');
```

I have seen the src and the orderby accepts only one parameter.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Possible duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17006309/how-to-use-order-by-for-multiple-columns-in-laravel-4

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use order by for multiple columns in laravel 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17006309/how-to-use-order-by-for-multiple-columns-in-laravel-4)

Comment: I'm using Backpack for Laravel, Crud module.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to chain any number of `orderBy` methods to CRUD's `query` property, which is the actual query that will be executed:

```
$this->crud->query = $this->crud->query->orderBy('name', 'desc')->orderBy('year', 'asc');
```

Comment: I have "select columns" with relations and they are sorted by id and not by value.  I have:

        `$this->crud->query = $this->crud->query->with(['artista' => function ($query) {
            $query->orderBy('nome_artista', 'asc');
        }])->get();`



But I get this error:



`SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'nome_artista' in 'order clause' (SQL: select * from artisti where artisti.id in (1, 3, 7) order by nome_artista asc)`



Eager loading does'nt work.