# Groupby in laravel leave grouped items in object

Tags: php, laravel, group-by

Right, not sure if I doing something wrong or it's a problem with Illuminate\Database in Laravel.

My code:

```
$sth = Insect::leftJoin('types', 'types.id', '=', 'families.type_id')
            ->select('types.name as types','families.id','families.name')
            ->get()
            ->groupBy('types');
```

Result before groupBy is:

```
[
{
    "types": "moths",
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Bombycidae"
},
{
    "types": "moths",
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Brahmaeidae"
},
{
    "types": "moths",
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Cossidae"
},
{
    "types": "larvas",
    "id": 6,
    "name": "test"
}]
```

But with groupBy:

```
{
"moths": [
    {
        "types": "moths",
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Bombycidae"
    },
    {
        "types": "moths",
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Brahmaeidae"
    },
    {
        "types": "moths",
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Cossidae"
    }
],
"larvas": [
    {
        "types": "larvas",
        "id": 6,
        "name": "test"
    }
]
}
```

So my problem is, I want to get rid  of that types in objects ...

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't put them in `select` then.

Comment: then result is: https://i.imgur.com/CkqohJ3.png

Comment: Can you try adding ->get() after group by? What happens?

Comment: then I will get only 1 result of each 'type' [lnik to code](https://i.imgur.com/nePrlh9.png)

Comment: Okay, can you try adding orderBy two times, first time with ID and second is "types". Refer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17006309/how-to-use-order-by-for-multiple-columns-in-laravel-4) and without groupBy

Comment: not sure if is that wha u want me to do: [link to code](https://i.imgur.com/StaQNrs.png) and results: [link to code](https://i.imgur.com/ogZv78V.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok first of all what you're doing is calling `groupBy` on the resulting collection and this is not related to the `GROUP BY` MySQL query clause which is very badly named (not relevant but just worth noting).

You can just map the result to what you need:

```
 $sth = Insect::leftJoin('types', 'types.id', '=', 'families.type_id')
                    ->select('types.name as types','families.id','families.name')
                    ->get()
                    ->groupBy('types')->map(function ($group) {
                          return $group->map(function ($value) {
                                return [ "id" => $value->id, "name" => $value->name ];
                          });
                     });
```

Comment: {
    "message": "Unknown column 'families.family_id' in 'on clause'"
}

Comment: I just added a `map` to your existing (working?) query. This would not have caused that message. You do seem to be missing a join with the `families` table in the query in your question. Did you mean to write `insects.family_id` instead?

Comment: [my code](https://i.imgur.com/LG6PFaS.png), so first code which I set as a comment works, but your code throw that error... :(

Comment: Actually u r right, my bad (in leftJoin) I didn't change family_id on type_id, and guess what, IT WORKS :) Results [link to code](https://i.imgur.com/Af7yRbZ.png)

Comment: Can you change in that code 'families.family_id' to 'families.type_id' ?

Comment: Take a look at: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships you can presumably have a model for families and then do `Families::with([ "insects" => function ($q) { return $q->select("id", "name"); }])->get()` it will probably end up in the same result. There's going to be one more query though but depending on your data structures that might be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the select type, and instead do the following:

```
$sth = Insect::leftJoin('types', 'types.id', '=', 'families.family_id')
    ->select('families.id','families.name')
    ->groupBy('insects.id', 'types.name')
    ->get();
```

Also, to see the raw query in action you can use the following

```
$sth = Insect::leftJoin('types', 'types.id', '=', 'families.family_id')
    ->select('families.id','families.name')
    ->groupBy('insects.id', 'types.name')
    ->toSql();

dd($sth);
```

You were selecting columns to use in your object, so if you remove it from the select statement, it will no longer show in your objects, you can also add the type to the `$hidden` input in your types model like so:

```
/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'name',
];
```

Grouping in laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset

Hiding rows from Arrays: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json

Comment: {
    "message": "Unknown column 'families.family_id' in 'on clause'"
} [link to code](https://i.imgur.com/lNTkqrq.png)

Comment: BUT: protected $hidden = ['types']; helped, thank you v much :)

Comment: Can you add ->toSql() on to the query and post the result for me?

Comment: then I receiving a plain text like: "select `families`.`id`, `families`.`name` from `families` left join `types` on `types`.`id` = `families`.`family_id` group by `insects`.`id`, `types`.`name`"

Comment: Do the query work the top one,the one with the get() rather than toSql();?

Comment: In first one I needed to change insects.id to types.id but then I recive only only one object of each 'types'. With second one only that plain text (sql querry) "select `families`.`id`, `families`.`name` from `families` left join `types` on `types`.`id` = `families`.`type_id` group by `types`.`id`, `types`.`name`"