# Laravel query returns unexpected order

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm using Laravel Query Builder to get a set of rows, ordering them by 2 columns, `ticket_id` then `id` (previously `created_at`). However the result orders them by `ticket_id` (correct), but the `id` (or `created_at`) secondary order is incorrect. Am I approaching this wrong, misunderstanding ordering?

Here's my query:

```
$responses = Response::where('status', '=', 'closed');
                       ->select('id', 'ticket_id', 'created_at', 'author_id')
                       ->orderBy('ticket_id', 'id')
                       ->get();
```

Which in turn, returns:

```
  0 => array:3 [
    "ticket_id" => 14
    "id" => 71
    "time" => "2018-05-25 08:55:03"
  ]
  1 => array:3 [
    "ticket_id" => 14
    "id" => 75
    "time" => "2018-05-25 12:48:45"
  ]
  2 => array:3 [
    "ticket_id" => 14
    "id" => 72
    "time" => "2018-05-25 08:55:53"
  ]
  3 => array:3 [
    "ticket_id" => 13
    "id" => 70
    "time" => "2018-05-25 08:53:50"
  ]
  4 => array:3 [
    "ticket_id" => 13
    "id" => 76
    "time" => "2018-05-29 12:30:46"
  ]
  5 => array:3 [
    "ticket_id" => 13
    "id" => 74
    "time" => "2018-05-25 11:30:36"
  ]
```

You see for ticket 14, the order is 71, 75, 72, rather than 71, 72, 75.

Here's the table structure too:

```
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ticket_id  | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| author_id  | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| status     | int(11)          | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| content    | text             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| assets     | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: Duplicate  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17006309/how-to-use-order-by-for-multiple-columns-in-laravel-4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`orderBy()` recives the column name as first parameter and the orientation `ASC, DESC` as the second.

`orderBy('ticket_id', 'id')` should be `orderBy('ticket_id', 'desc')->orderBy('id','desc')`

Comment: I'm such an idiot for missing that in the docs. Thanks, been banging my head against the desk for too long with this one.