# How to order by column in nested 2 level relationship in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, orm, nested, foreign-keys

I have 3 tables: `reports`, `fields` and `report_fields` which is a pivot between the other 2. What i need to do is order `report_field.field` by the position `column` in the `field` table.

I tried ordering in the relation in the `Models` or when using `with` but I may be doing it wrong. 
ex:

```
$query = Report::with([ 'reportFields.field' => function ($q) {
    $q->orderBy('position', 'asc');
    //$q->orderByRaw("fields.position DESC");
},
```

Can someone give a basic example of ordering a 2 level nested relationship?

Edit: I do not need to order by any column in the base table but the list of entries in the pivot table by an column in the second table.

Edit2:

To give an example how the output should be ordered:

```
Report
    ReportField
        Field.position = 1
    ReportField
        Field.position = 2
    ReportField
        Field.position = 3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Use Order By for Multiple Columns in Laravel 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17006309/how-to-use-order-by-for-multiple-columns-in-laravel-4)

Comment: Not the same thing. The problem is ordering by a nested relation by 2 levels. The link you specified is talking about ordering in a single table by 2 columns.

Comment: Try to use trough relationship in your models https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: I need to access the "pivot" table `report_fied` for other table fields unique to that report so i cannot use the standard hasManyThrough. The relationships are made using belongsTo/hasMany.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add your needed ordering on the relation of the first table `reports`:

```
public function reportFields()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ReportFields::class)
        ->select('report_fields.*')
        ->join('fields', 'report_fields.field_id', 'fields.id')
        ->orderBy('fields.position', 'asc');
}
```