# Eager Load sorting on belongToMany relation with relation on Pivot model

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

both, Project as well as Member classes have belongToMany relations and my pivot model MemberProject has table `member_project` with additional `role_id` field forming `project_id,member_id,role_id` triplet also has belongsTo relation to Role class

I am trying to order by a field in my role relation so came up with the following

```php
$project->load(['members' => function ($qry) {
    $qry
    ->selectRaw('roles.order as `order`, roles.name as `title`, members.*')
    ->join('roles', 'roles.id', '=', 'member_project.role_id')
    ->orderBy('roles.order', 'desc')->get();
}]);
```

which does the job but this sql is executed twice for some reason.

```sql
SELECT `roles`.*, `members`.*,
  `member_project`.`project_id` AS `pivot_project_id`,
  `member_project`.`member_id` AS `pivot_member_id`,
  `member_project`.`role_id` AS `pivot_role_id`
FROM `members`
  INNER JOIN `member_project` ON `members`.`id` = `member_project`.`member_id`
  INNER JOIN `roles` ON `roles`.`id` = `member_project`.`role_id`
WHERE `member_project`.`project_id` in (2)
ORDER BY `roles`.`order`;
```

as you noticed I am adding additional join using the method from Laravel documentation on [Constraining Eager loads](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads). of course when there is no join, only one query is executed. here is exact the same query executed twice. why?

if you know any other way to sort many-to-many relation based on pivot model relation, please let me know.

Comment: Please remove this  `->get();`  from load method

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to order by column in nested 2 level relationship in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55566752/how-to-order-by-column-in-nested-2-level-relationship-in-laravel)