# Laravel 6.0 Eloquent - sort by date and status

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Trying to order my table by newest Date first, then the status. The Status can be (New, In Review, Declined, Closed) and Status is an enum field in the database.

I've tried several things with no success. This is the closest I've got with this code. I'm new to Laravel so not sure how to do this.

```
$inquiries = Inquiry::all()->sortByDesc('created_at')->sortByDesc('Status')->values();
```

That produces this:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
|     Name          |      Created At    |      Status       |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|     Richard       |      05/02/2020    |       New         |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|     James         |      05/02/2020    |       New         |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|     Christine     |      04/16/2020    |      Declined     |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|     Charles       |      04/14/2020    |       New         |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|     Judy          |      03/13/2020    |      In Review    |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|     Paul          |      01/12/2020    |       New         |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

I would like it to look like this where it's sorted by Date, with the newest Date first, then with status = "New". I would like it to look like this:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
|     Name          |      Created At    |      Status       |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|     Richard       |      05/02/2020    |       New         |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|     James         |      05/02/2020    |       New         |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|     Charles       |      04/14/2020    |       New         |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|     Paul          |      01/12/2020    |       New         |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|     Christine     |      04/16/2020    |      Declined     |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|     Judy          |      03/13/2020    |      In Review    |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Is the date in that format on your database? Why you are sorting by 'created_at' but showing 'Date' on that tables?

Comment: so you want to sort by status first (more priority) then sort by date ASC (use sortByAsc instead of sortByDesc)

Comment: `$inquiries = Inquiry::orderBy('created_at','desc')->orderBy('Status','desc')->get();`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Correct, date should be 'Create At' not "Date". I edited it.

Comment: Ok, I was going to suggest almost the same as in  Christophe Hubert's comment, in other words, ordering in the database query, but orderning by staus first and then by date `$inquiries = Inquiry::orderBy('Status','desc')->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();`

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks for the help guys.  ```$inquiries = Inquiry::orderBy('status','asc')->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, let's see whether you need to use `orderBy()` or `sortBy()`.

**sortBy()** / **sortByDesc()**

The methods `sortBy()` and `sortByDesc()` are used to sort the data after fetching results from the database.

**orderBy()**

The method `orderBy` is the same as the **SQL** `ORDER BY` statement. This will sort the database records and then output the results.

---

**Answer**

Here you need to use `orderBy()` instead of `sortByDesc()`. [It's almost a duplicate question, Find the original here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17006309/how-to-use-order-by-for-multiple-columns-in-laravel-4)

```php
// Make sure column names are correct
$inquiries = Inquiry::orderBy('status', 'ASC') // or DESC
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a function to the `sortBy` function on the collection allowing you to specify which value should be used for sorting. This way, you can also combine two values for sorting.

```php
Inquiry::all()->sortBy(function ($inquiry) {
    return sprintf('%s%s', $inquiry->created_at, $inquiry->status);      
})->values();
```

You can read more about it here: https://laravel.com/docs/collections#method-sortby